# Looping with variable data set

Tags: excel, vba, loops, unpivot

Based on the picture I would like for each animal to be copied to each Set/# (and for the outcome to be on Sheet 2).

Example of Goal
[image]

The issue is that it won't always be a set of 14 it can vary based on the data but the Animals would stay the same (no more then 4).

Below is what I have, granted it is not based on the picture. That is an example.

```vb
Sub DowithIf()

    rw = 5
    cl = 2
    rw = 1000

    Do While rw < erw
        If Cells(rw, cl) <> Cells(rw - 1, cl) Then
            Cells(rw, cl + 1) = Cells(rw, cl)

            Range("A5:B5").Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("Sheet2").Select
            Range("A2").Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Range("A2:B4").Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Selection.FillDown
            Sheets("Data").Select
            Range("E3:J5").Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("Sheet2").Select
            Range("C2").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
              :=False, Transpose:=False
        ElseIf Cells(rw, cl) = "" Then
            Exit Do
        End If
        rw = rw + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd find this easier if you looked at VBA as more of a programming language than a macro recorder. In your example, the task is really just to create an array whose row count is:

> *number of set names* * *number of set items*

All you'd need to do is populate that array following a certain pattern. In your example it would be:

> set number n with all set items, set number n + 1 with all set items, etc.

Skeleton code would look something like this:

```
Const SET_NAMES_ROW_START As Long = 6
Const SET_ITEMS_ROW_START As Long = 6
Const SET_NAMES_COL As String = "A"
Const SET_ITEMS_COL As String = "E"
Const OUTPUT_ROW_START As Long = 6
Const OUTPUT_COL As String = "G"

Dim names() As Variant, items() As Variant, output() As Variant
Dim namesCount As Long, itemsCount As Long
Dim idx As Long, nameIdx As Long, itemIdx As Long

'Read the set values.
With Sheet1
    names = .Range( _
                .Cells(SET_NAMES_ROW_START, SET_NAMES_COL), _
                .Cells(.Rows.Count, SET_NAMES_COL).End(xlUp)) _
               .Resize(, 2).Value2
    items = .Range( _
                .Cells(SET_ITEMS_ROW_START, SET_ITEMS_COL), _
                .Cells(.Rows.Count, SET_ITEMS_COL).End(xlUp)) _
               .Value2
End With

'Dimension the output array.
namesCount = UBound(names, 1)
itemsCount = UBound(items, 1)

ReDim output(1 To namesCount * itemsCount, 1 To 3)

'Populate the output array.
nameIdx = 1
itemIdx = 1
For idx = 1 To namesCount * itemsCount
    output(idx, 1) = names(nameIdx, 1)
    output(idx, 2) = names(nameIdx, 2)
    output(idx, 3) = items(itemIdx, 1)
    itemIdx = itemIdx + 1
    If itemIdx > itemsCount Then
        'Increment the name index by 1.
        nameIdx = nameIdx + 1
        'Reset the item index to 1.
        itemIdx = 1
    End If
Next

'Write array to the output sheet.
Sheet1.Cells(OUTPUT_ROW_START, OUTPUT_COL).Resize(UBound(output, 1), UBound(output, 2)).Value = output
```

Comment: Thank you so much this was very helpful! I do have 1 follow-up question assuming there were to be another column added next to 'Animal" and still want to keep the output the same (see updated VBA output image) what would be added/changed in the code?

Comment: Just expand the `items` array by one column and then read the second column into the output array: `output(idx, 4) = items(itemIdx, 2)`

Comment: I tried expanding the items array by 1 column + added output(idx, 4) = items(itemIdx, 2) into the output array. But i keep getting a debug error. just to make sure i am increasing the items array correctly could you paste the part that i am suppose to increase. I think thats were i might going wrong but im not a 100% sure. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

So I think this will let you dynamically pick the size of your data set. I'm assuming that the column headers will always be at Row 5 as pictured. It loops through each input column and provides a unique output in H, I, and J. Disclaimer: I didn't get to test this as I'm not on my work PC.

```
Sub MixTheStuff()

'sets size of data in A (Set).  -5 for the header row as noted
x = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 5  
 
'sets size of data in B (#)
y = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row - 5

'sets size of data in E (Animal)
z = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row - 5   

i=6 'First row after the headers

For sThing = 1 to x    'set thing
For nThing = 1 to y    'number thing
For aThing = 1 to z    'animal thing

    'Pastes the value of the stuff (Set, #, and Animal respectively)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").cell(i,10) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").cell(x,1).value
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").cell(i,11) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").cell(y,2).value
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").cell(i,12) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").cell(z,5).value

i = i + 1 'Go to the next output row

Next sThing
Next nThing
Next aThing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Sort of Unpivot

- This will allow you to handle maximally 1023 animals.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub SortOfUnpivot()
    
    Const FirstRow As Long = 6
    Const LastRowCol As String = "E"
    Const dstFirstCell As String = "H6"
    Dim srcCols As Variant
    srcCols = VBA.Array("A", "B", "E")
    
    Dim LB As Long
    LB = LBound(srcCols)
    Dim UB As Long
    UB = UBound(srcCols)
    Dim srcCount As Long
    srcCount = UB - LB + 1
    
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, LastRowCol).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Cells(FirstRow, LastRowCol).Resize(LastRow - FirstRow + 1)
    Dim Source As Variant
    ReDim Source(LB To UB)
    
    Dim j As Long
    For j = LB To UB
        Source(j) = rng.Offset(, Columns(srcCols(j)).Column - rng.Column).Value
    Next j
    
    Dim UBS As Long
    UBS = UBound(Source(UB))
    
    Dim Dest As Variant
    ReDim Dest(1 To UBS ^ 2, 1 To srcCount)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim k As Long
    
    For j = 1 To UBS
        k = k + 1
        For i = 1 + (j - 1) * UBS To UBS + (j - 1) * UBS
            Dest(i, 1) = Source(0)(k, 1)
            Dest(i, 2) = Source(1)(k, 1)
            Dest(i, 3) = Source(2)(i - (j - 1) * UBS, 1)
        Next i
    Next j
    
    Range(dstFirstCell).Resize(UBound(Dest), srcCount).Value = Dest
    
    
End Sub
```