# Adding column to VBA loop

Tags: excel, vba, unpivot

i currently have the code below which is pulling the Current Code image (where for each Set and # it's adding the animal), however I would like to add an new column "Color" and be able to have it do the same thing that the current code is doing just with a new column (as shown in Goal for Code Image).

I tried adding the following by I keep getting a debugging error.

```
output(idx, 4) = items(itemIdx, 2)
```

If anyone can help I would really appreacite it! Thanks :)

Current Code
[image]

Goal for Code
[image]

```
Const SET_NAMES_ROW_START As Long = 6
Const SET_ITEMS_ROW_START As Long = 6
Const SET_NAMES_COL As String = "A"
Const SET_ITEMS_COL As String = "E"
Const OUTPUT_ROW_START As Long = 6
Const OUTPUT_COL As String = "G"

Dim names() As Variant, items() As Variant, output() As Variant
Dim namesCount As Long, itemsCount As Long
Dim idx As Long, nameIdx As Long, itemIdx As Long

'Read the set values.
With Sheet1
    names = .Range( _
                .Cells(SET_NAMES_ROW_START, SET_NAMES_COL), _
                .Cells(.Rows.Count, SET_NAMES_COL).End(xlUp)) _
               .Resize(, 2).Value2
    items = .Range( _
                .Cells(SET_ITEMS_ROW_START, SET_ITEMS_COL), _
                .Cells(.Rows.Count, SET_ITEMS_COL).End(xlUp)) _
               .Value2
End With

'Dimension the output array.
namesCount = UBound(names, 1)
itemsCount = UBound(items, 1)

ReDim output(1 To namesCount * itemsCount, 1 To 3)

'Populate the output array.
nameIdx = 1
itemIdx = 1
For idx = 1 To namesCount * itemsCount
    output(idx, 1) = names(nameIdx, 1)
    output(idx, 2) = names(nameIdx, 2)
    output(idx, 3) = items(itemIdx, 1)
    itemIdx = itemIdx + 1
    If itemIdx > itemsCount Then
        'Increment the name index by 1.
        nameIdx = nameIdx + 1
        'Reset the item index to 1.
        itemIdx = 1
    End If
Next

'Write array to the output sheet.
Sheet1.Cells(OUTPUT_ROW_START, OUTPUT_COL).Resize(UBound(output, 1), UBound(output, 2)).Value = output
```

Comment: Shouldn't your `ReDim` statement use a second dimension of `1 To 4` ?

Comment: @PeterT I changed it to '1 to 4' but its still not pulling in the other column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Sort of Unpivot

- `' ***` is indicating the differences between this and the [initial code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64760939/looping-with-infinite-data-set/64761985#64761985).

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub SortOfUnpivot()
    
    Const FirstRow As Long = 6
    Const LastRowCol As String = "E"
    Const dstFirstCell As String = "H6"
    Dim srcCols As Variant
    srcCols = VBA.Array("A", "B", "E", "F") ' ***
    
    Dim LB As Long
    LB = LBound(srcCols)
    Dim UB As Long
    UB = UBound(srcCols)
    Dim srcCount As Long
    srcCount = UB - LB + 1
    
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, LastRowCol).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Cells(FirstRow, LastRowCol).Resize(LastRow - FirstRow + 1)
    Dim Source As Variant
    ReDim Source(LB To UB)
    
    Dim j As Long
    For j = LB To UB
        Source(j) = rng.Offset(, Columns(srcCols(j)).Column - rng.Column).Value
    Next j
    
    Dim UBS As Long
    UBS = UBound(Source(UB))
    
    Dim Dest As Variant
    ReDim Dest(1 To UBS ^ 2, 1 To srcCount)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim k As Long
    
    For j = 1 To UBS
        k = k + 1
        For i = 1 + (j - 1) * UBS To UBS + (j - 1) * UBS
            Dest(i, 1) = Source(0)(k, 1)
            Dest(i, 2) = Source(1)(k, 1)
            Dest(i, 3) = Source(2)(i - (j - 1) * UBS, 1)
            Dest(i, 4) = Source(3)(i - (j - 1) * UBS, 1) '***
        Next i
    Next j
    
    Range(dstFirstCell).Resize(UBound(Dest), srcCount).Value = Dest

End Sub
```

Comment: I actually have a question, so I noticed that Animal and Color are being looped 4 times but it’s not being attributed to the Set and # columns. Not sure if that makes sense but I’m trying to get Animal and Color to go to Set A #1 4 times and then for Set B #2 4 times...etc.  but what’s happening is Set A1=Cat White, B2=dog black, C3=rat blue and D4=horse red. 
Appreciate the help!

Comment: The result is exactly like your image is showing. You are describing the result that you would get if `Dest(i, 3) = Source(2)(k, 1)` and `Dest(i, 4) = Source(3)(k, 1)`. If the result should be different than in the image, then just post an image with the correct result and I'll look into it.

Comment: that fixed it thank you. i do have another question, so based on the images the output goes up to D, ideally i would like the output to populate up to the last Set. in this case it would be up to N but assuming there is a lot more then N want part would i change. thanks again!!

Comment: also if i would like to change the destention from H6 to Sheet A3 how would i write that out?

Comment: This needs a rewrite. You didn't explain your requirements too well. Let's start from the beginning: You want e.g. these 4 animals with all the sets in column `A` and `B` i.e. the number of sets might (will) be different than the number of animals. You want the possibility to write the result in another worksheet. Please do confirm and add if I misunderstood or missed something.

Comment: Sorry about that at the moment I didn’t think I wanted to move the output. but yes so all 4 animals (E) + colors (F) to got with x amount of sets (A) + #s (B). And for the output to go onto Sheet2 cell A3.